# javascript not working in embed svg file

Tags: javascript, svg

I just start learning SVG. got this example code from [Manipulating SVG Documents Using ECMAScript (Javascript) and the DOM](http://www.carto.net/papers/svg/manipulating_svg_with_dom_ecmascript/). I change it a little:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="300">
  <script type="text/ecmascript">
  <![CDATA[
    function changeRectColor(evt) {
      var red = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      evt.target.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","rgb("+ red +","+ red+","+red+")");
    }
  ]]>
  </script>
  <g id="firstGroup">
    <rect id="myBlueRect" width="100" height="50" x="40" y="20" fill="blue" onclick="changeRectColor(evt)"/>
    <text x="40" y="100">Click on rectangle to change it's color.</text>
  </g>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

It works just fine. I move to separated SVG file, then js code stop working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="exampl3a.svg" />   
  <script type="text/ecmascript">
  <![CDATA[
    function changeRectColor(evt) {
      var red = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      evt.target.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","rgb("+ red +","+ red+","+red+")");
    }
  ]]>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

SVG file: exampl3a.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="300">
  <g id="firstGroup">
    <rect id="myBlueRect" width="100" height="50" x="40" y="20" fill="blue" onclick="changeRectColor(evt)"/>
    <text x="40" y="100">Click on rectangle to change it's color.</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

what should I do?

Thanks
Wes

Comment: You don't need to wrap JS in cdata anymore...

Comment: I got the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333878/google-chrome-wont-accept-contentdocument-or-contentwindow "contentDocument ... (for svg objects from svg files) will work fine if the code is from a web server, but when I copy the code to a local file, it will not work."

Comment: sorry, I forgot step 1:   Change
  document.getElementById("kreis1").setAttribute("fill", "blue");
  To

document.getElementById("object1").contentDocument.getElementById("kreis1").setAttribute("fill", "blue"); this works Firefox but not Google Chrome

Comment: Chrome and Firefox have slightly different security models. Chrome will not allow what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put svg into a different file, then it will be in another document, and you'll need to bind to that document, using `getSVGDocument`. And yes, this will still not work in Chrome for local files (only for the website, or unless Chrome is run with corresponding command-line switch).

SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="300">
  <g id="firstGroup">
    <rect id="myBlueRect" width="100" height="50" x="40" y="20" fill="blue" />
    <text x="40" y="100">Click on rectangle to change it's color.</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<object id='mySvg' type="image/svg+xml" data="example3a.svg" />
<script type="text/ecmascript">
    function changeRectColor(evt) {
        var red = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
        evt.target.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","rgb("+ red +","+ red+","+red+")");
    }

    var obj = document.getElementById('mySvg');
    obj.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var svgDoc= obj.getSVGDocument();
        var elem = svgDoc.getElementById("myBlueRect");
        elem.addEventListener('click', changeRectColor);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my experience: It getSVGDocument works on a server (Github worked), but not for local files. If you have an older computer (Windows XP) it will work on that, too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).